# Asp .Net 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 IIS 8 - website runs FAST on LAN, very slow over internet

Tags: .net, iis-8

Our users are reporting a ton of slowness on our two main websites.  This would be accessing them from the outside work, from different physical locations, and different browsers and different devices.  And yet, other users are fine.   Response speeds on our website externally are like 7-10 seconds, which is insanely slow.

Internally, on our LAN the sites are blazing fast.  The pages open immediately.  This is a solution that we ran on .Net 2.0 on a Windows Server 2003 box up until very recently.  we moved it to the new box running .Net 4.0 and Integrated pipeline mode this past weekend after extensive testing.  No issues that we could see.

However, now that the site is live on the new server we are having a fair amount of issues.

Any ideas what we could be dealing with here?   We rebooted all the physical hardware, even though there is nothing to point to hardware as the problem.   It seems to me like a configuration mistake somewhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: I should also say, that we can see the problem externally when we check the site.  The site loads either 300-500 ms (acceptable) or 15,000 ms (NOT acceptable).  There appears to be no in between.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we found the problem.  It turns out we had two A records setup on our hosting server for DNS.  The first was meant to be the primary - for all traffic.  The second was failover only, when the first was down for more than 5 minutes.  Unfortunately, our hosting provider (register.com) does not offer the ability to set priority or failover for DNS.  So basically, they were giving out either IP Address as the host IP.

Problem was, our failover service was having an error on the modem.  We rebooted the modem, everything is flowing correctly now.

WE are going to ditch Register.com DNS and go to another company for proper DNS failover setup.